# Python multithreading with asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-asyncio

I have a websocket subscribed to a client's news feed. And as soon as a receive a news, I want to take an action like the following:

```
from client import Client, SocketManager
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from time import time

class client(Client):
def __init__():
    self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

async def start_websockets(self):        
    self.sm = await SocketManager.create(self.loop, self, self.handle_evt)
    await self.sm.subscribe()
    while not self.received:
        await asyncio.sleep(10, loop=self.loop)

async def handle_evt(self, msg):
      self.msg = msg
      subject1 = msg['data']['subjetct']
      subject2 = msg['data']['subjetct2']

      with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
            future_buy = executor.submit(self.process, subject1)
            future_sell = executor.submit(self.process, subject2)
            
            future_buy.result()
            future_sell.result()

 def process(self, subject):
      if 'type' in subject:
         # do something
      else:
         # do something
 
 async def main(self):
     await self.start_websockets()
     while True:
        if time() > start + 60*5:
            start = time()
            print(self.msg)
 def start(self):
    self.loop.run_until_complete(self.main())
```

However, it looks like it get stuck in the ThreadPoolExecutor. I am probably missing a await somewhere, but i am not very familiar with asyncio.
Can someone help me out on this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `asyncio`'s inbuilt executor and wrapper via [`loop.run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor):

```
async def handle_evt(self, msg):
      self.msg = msg
      subject1 = msg['data']['subjetct']
      subject2 = msg['data']['subjetct2']

      loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
      future_buy = loop.run_in_executor(None, self.process, subject1)
      future_sell = loop.run_in_executor(None, self.process, subject2)
      # allow other coroutines to run while waiting
      await future_buy
      await future_sell
```

A `concurrent.futures.Future` is inherently synchronous – waiting for [`Future.result()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future.result) *blocks* the current thread. Executing it inside an event loop thus blocks the event loop, including all coroutines.

The `asyncio` wrapper provides an [`asyncio.Future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.Future) instead, which allows asynchronous waiting for results.